# alternative to eval in python to read input from dat file

Tags: python, numpy, security

Recently, I found that eval is not good in python regarding security and so on..
I have searched via internet to catch best alternative for my case, however, could not find
can anyone help or suggest me with the best option,
I wanna read an array from input.dat and make it as numpy array
I attach the code, and .dat file

```
with open('trial.dat', 'r') as f:
     data = f.readlines()
     data = [(d+' ')[:d.find('#')].rstrip() for d in data]
x_1=eval(data[0])
y=np.concatenate(x_1)
```

Data in the file as example will be the following:

```
[[1,2,np.repeat(3,1)]]
```

Comment: `ast.literal_eval()` would be the standard solution, but I don't think it can handle the `np.array()` expression there.

Comment: If you're going to put function calls in the file, you're stuck with using `eval()`.

Comment: BLUF: If you are the sole person in the chain of custody then `eval` is quite all right. If you're getting these files from unknown sources then not a great idea to be executing them with `eval`.

Comment: @NanoBennett
actually, the end user who will write the input.dat file, however, I also wanna learn how to do something like that in a safe way, 
So if you know, how to convert string to numpy array ? in a better safe way .. let me know 

or add like try or if condition, 
that would be great.. 

Looking to hearing any suggestions, 

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

If you are only wanting to use `numpy` operations then you can simply add it as a `locals` dictionary and exclude builtins. Something like this. You'll have to get more specific if you only want certain functions to be run like np.sin or np.array, etc...

```
import numpy as np
locals = {'np': np}
builtins = {'__builtins__': None}
x = '[[1,2,np.repeat(3,1)]]'
x2 = eval(x, builtins, locals)

x2[0][2]
Out[22]: array([3])
```

Now if someone slips an `os` call in there it won't execute.

```
x = 'os.makedirs(\'C:/test\')'
x2 = eval(x, builtins, locals)
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

Comment: Sounds a good idea, what about also the following idea:
data to be used like: 
1,2,np.repeat(3,1)

x=1,2,np.repeat(3,1)
y=np.fromstring(x_11,dtype=int, sep=',')

Now, the only problem how to repeat 3 n times 
Please remember, this will be via an input file so will be a string and then I convert it 

Any suggestions,